# Selecting numbers only in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to select all the digits from a given string. I tried with the code below, but it does not return all the numbers in the string:

```
var match = /\d+/.exec("+12 (345)-678.90[]");
console.log(match.toString());
```

It only returns `12`, while I expect it to return `1234567890`.

Comment: use global in regex.

Comment: You're only selecting one match. There are four matches in there. `"+12 (345)-678.90[]".replace(/\D/g, "");` should do it

Comment: Try something like `/\d+/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `global` flag, it will return you an array of matched data the you can use `join()` it.

```
"+12 (345)-678.90[]".match(/\d+/g).join('');
```

```js
alert("+12 (345)-678.90[]".match(/\d+/g).join(''))
```

Answer (score 5):

simple implementation will be

```
var value='+12 (345)-678.90[]'.replace(/\D+/g, '');
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
"+12 (345)-678.90[]".match(/\d+/g)
```

Comment: This was returning the matches with `,` .. like 12,345,678,90. Adding `.join('')` returned perfectly was required. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `\d+` pattern will return *consecutive* digits only, and since you running `exec` once without `g` option, it will only give you the first occurrence of consecutive digits.

Use this:

```js
var re = /\d+/g; 
var str = '+12 (345)-678.90[]';
var res = "";
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res += m[0];
}
alert(res);
```

Output is `1234567890`, as we append found digit sequences to the `res` variable.

Comment: @Juhana: Good catch, looks like it is redundant here. There are cases when we need to count matches, and then it is useful.